# ImportError using imp.find_module from subdirectory

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

I have a project:

```
main
|---src.py
|---frame_select.py
|-----shellsdir
      |---script_select.py
      |------scriptsdir
             |---test.py
```

Main has script that passes arguments to `frame_select.py` which then looks inside `shelldir` for the appropriate script based on the argument passed. It returns and does so using:

```
import imp, sys

sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/shellsdir/')

def module_import(mod_name):
   fp, p, d = imp.find_module(mod_name)
   py_mod = imp.load_module(mod_name,
                            fp,
                            p,
                            d)

def pick(value, window):
   if value == 'name_passed':
      c_mod = module_import('specific_name')
      c_mod.populate(window)
```

There are about 16 scripts in `shellsdir` so this picks based on the passed argument which script to load while looking in `shellsdir`. Within `shellsdir` is another directory called `scriptsdir` and a file `script_selector`. The file looks like this:

```
import imp, sys

sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/scriptsdir/')

def module_import(mod_name):
   fp, p, d = imp.find_module(mod_name)
   py_mod = imp.load_module(mod_name,
                            fp,
                            p,
                            d)
```

Essentially just reusing code, but now I am pointing at `scriptsdir` for a program to pass an argument to the `module_import()` function. However, I am not getting `ImportError: No module named 'name_passed'`.

I've done a `print sys.path` and the `/path/to/shellsdir/` and `/path/to/scriptsdir` are both there. The module name matches, so I am not sure why the error.

Comment: Do _shellsdir_ and _scriptsdir_ have the _\_\_init\_\_.py(c)_ file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**for frame_select.py**:
Updated with relative path to the `src.py` file.

```
import imp, sys

sys.path.insert(0, './shellsdir')

def module_import(mod_name):
   fp, p, d = imp.find_module(mod_name)
   py_mod = imp.load_module(mod_name,
                            fp,
                            p,
                            d)

def pick(value, window):
   if value == 'name_passed':
      c_mod = module_import('specific_name')
      c_mod.populate(window)
```

**for script_select.py**:
Updated with relative path to the `src.py` file.

```
import imp, sys

sys.path.insert(0, './shellsdir/scriptsdir/')

def module_import(mod_name):
   fp, p, d = imp.find_module(mod_name)
   py_mod = imp.load_module(mod_name,
                            fp,
                            p,
                            d)
```

It may be worth noting that `../scriptsdir/` would not work. However, I had figured this out earlier but didn't think it worked due to very long import time. Forgot I had about 20 modules (for testing purpose) in the `test.py` file and that's what caused the delay.